# ImageView black and white not working in alert dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want the imageview in my custom alert dialog to be black and white.
The correct way to do this (after reasearch) is...

```
ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix();
        matrix.setSaturation(0);

        ColorMatrixColorFilter filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix);
        imageview.setColorFilter(filter);
```

However, this is not working when my imageview is an my custom alert dialog.

Here is my code:

private void showDialogForTodayItemClicked() {

```
// custom dialog
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_daily_food_clicked);
dialog.setTitle("Title...");

ImageView imageview = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image_view_dialog_background_today);
imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.avocados_small);

ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix();
matrix.setSaturation(0);

ColorMatrixColorFilter filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix);
imageview.setColorFilter(filter);

dialog.show();
```

}

Here is the xml for the dialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:id="@+id/dialog_daily_food_relative_layout"

    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#81383838"></LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/image_view_dialog_background_today"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="MORE INFO"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="DONE"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"/>




</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks so much to all.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, when i used this it worked:

```
imageview.setImageResource(currentItem.getImage());
```

(instead of setBackgroundImage).